# Navigate URL from Silverlight control

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am working in a Silverlight control where I need to upload some static data synchronously from a XML file. The file is in my same Web Server. I can get the URI of the control like so:

```
HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri.ToString();
```

That returns the URI with the query that shows the control inclusive:

```
http://example.com:8085/MyWeb/CustomPage.aspx?waid=a1a5780a8ddea6c517ae1-b4ef&nid=id78
```

What I need from there is only http://example.com:8085/MyWeb (which will always be the same except for the host name/port) I do not want to hard code that because this will be deployed in several servers. So, what I'd like to do is get the web site URI. I tried several things like localpath, host, AbsolutePath and others in the DocumentUri object but none seem to give me what I need. How can I do that without doing a ton of manipulation.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var absoluteUri = Application.Current.Host.Source.AbsoluteUri;
int lengthWithoutParams = absoluteUri.IndexOf("?") < 0 ? absoluteUri.Length : absoluteUri.IndexOf("?");
string uploadUrl = absoluteUri.Substring(0, lengthWithoutParams).Replace("/ClientBin/<YourXAPfile>.xap", filePath);
```

And finally:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(uploadUrl));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("urlString"));
```